# Docker port not overriden

Tags: docker, port, boot2docker

I want to expose a docker container port on a different host port.

```
docker run -d --net="host" --name="couchpotato2" -p 5555:5050 ...
```

However, I don't get the mapping of `5555 -> 5050`. Any idea why?

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
114ae1617632        needo/couchpotato   "/sbin/my_init"     3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            couchpotato3
```

Here is the docker image I'm using:
https://github.com/needo37/couchpotato

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the use of host networking:

```
--net="host"
```

Explained in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#network-settings)

> Publishing ports and linking to other containers will not work when
>   --net is anything other than the default (bridge).